# Question about using ServiceModelEx's "WCFLogbook" from "Programming WCF Services" book

Tags: sql, wcf, servicemodelex

I am attempting to compile/run a sample WCF application from Juval Lowy's website (author of **Programming WCF Services** & founder of **IDesign**). Of course the example application utilizes Juval's **ServiceModelEx** library and logs faults/errors to a "WCFLogbook" database.  Unfortunately, when the sample app faults, I get the following new error:

> **"Cannot open database "WCFLogbook"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user
>   'Bill-PC\Bill'."**

I suspect the error occurs as a result of not finding the "WCFLogbook" database, which I believe still needs to be created.  Included in the library source directory, there are two files -WCFLogbookDataSet.xsd and WCFLogbook.sql; which neither seem to be referenced anywhere within the library code.  This leads me to beleive that the sql and xsd files are there to be used to create the database somehow in SQL.  Could someone please advise me if I am going in the correct direction here and if whether these files can be used to create the database (and if so, how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to execute the .sql file in Sql Server Management Studio to create the database, then you will have to change the connectionstring in the config file to point to your instance of the WCFLogBook Database.